# Can we update a text index in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have a mongoDB database. In a collection there is an existing Text Index, which is not used anywhere now(it was being used, but now that functionality is now removed). And I wanted to update that index with new fields. I didn't find any updateIndex function in [MongoDB doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

So I wrote a script that will first drop that particular index and create a new one in its place because mongoDB allows only one text index at a time. 
I want to know that is there any update command? 
Is this a good approach or is there any better approach than this? 
Thanks!

```
conn = new Mongo();

db = conn.getDB("test");

db.books.dropIndex({name: "old-index"});

db.books.createIndex({
    "notes": "text", "articles.description":
    "text", "categories": "text"
  },
  {name: "new-index"});
```